# Lining figures with osf option in newtx

Tags: fonts

I am using `newtx` with old style figures, specified as

```
\usepackage[osf]{newtxtext}
```

However, at one place I need lining figures instead.  Is it possible to call lining figures just for that one instance?

I already tried

```
{\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ntxrx}\fontfamily\familydefault\selectfont<number>}
```

but I get error

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1\ntxrx\m\n' undefined
```

Comment: If it's just a single instance of needing lining numerals in text mode, simply use math mode to render the number.

Comment: @Mico I have tried and I got a bit larger numbers than text.

Comment: In that case, you *must* be doing something extra which you haven't mentioned in your posting. Try compiling the following test document: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[osf]{newtxtext} \usepackage{newtxmath} \usepackage{color} \newlength\mylen \settowidth\mylen{$1234567890$} \begin{document} .$1234567890$\kern-\mylen\color{red}\liningnums{1234567890}. \end{document}`. The two sets of numerals should coincide *perfectly*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\liningnums`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
1234567890 vs \liningnums{1234567890}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! How come I didn't find this command in `newtx` manual?

Comment: @Pygmalion Uhm, you're right, though I believe I remember reading it. But I've got the impression that the doc has been heavily rewritten. I'll ping Michael, it's something which should be documented (it's in fact a pretty common macro by font packages which provide both old style and lining figures).

Comment: @campa -- Oddly, the macros `\oldstylenums`, `\liningnums`, `\tabularnums` and `\proportionalnums` are mentioned in the `newpx` manual, but not in the `newtx` manual. I suspect the omission is due to a workflow error creeping in during a package update.